# modular development in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, modular

I'd like to create flutter apps by creating small "sub-Apps" and using them as modules.
Is there a good solution available for modular programming in flutter?

My module system is working when I have a "module" as the whole project folder.
But is there a way by doing it with a bundled file instead of the whole project folder,
so that bundle_a can access to a method from bundle_b?

Answer (score 0):

Dart (as well as Flutter) uses a package system. It's the way you should go:
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/using-packages

Comment: But is it possible without sharing it on pub.dev?

Comment: Yes Michael. You may use local packages.